# How do I use -webkit- prefix in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, webkit

I have a state `fontSize` that can be changed by user via an input field.
I then use `fontSize` to dynamically set the font size of some text on the page:

```
const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState("32px");

// sets the font size provided by user
// is fired when user clicks "apply" button
function applyFontSize(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const userInput = document.querySelector("#font-size-input").value
        setFontSize(userInput)
}

   
return (
        <form className="wrapper">
                <div className="option-wrapper">
                    <input 
                        className="input"
                        id="font-size-input"
                        placeholder="Font size (default 32px)"
                    />
                    <button 
                        className="apply-button"
                        onClick={applyFontSize}
                    >
                    Apply
                    </button>
                </div>
        </form>

  
        <div className="text-wrapper">
                <div 
                    className="top-text"
                    style={{
                        fontSize: fontSize
                    }}
                >
                    {topText}
                </div>
                <div 
                    className="bottom-text"
                    style={{
                        fontSize: fontSize
                    }}
                >
                    {bottomText}
                </div>
         </div>
    )
```

So, in the code above I use `style={{ fontSize: fontSize }}`

Now, I want to do the same thing with `text-stroke` property, which is only supported with the `-webkit-` prefix

Essentially, I want something like this:

```
const [textStroke, setTextStroke] = useState("2px")

function applyStroke(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const input = document.querySelector(".input-field").value
        setTextStroke(input)
}

return (
   <main>
      <div
      style={{ -webkit-text-stroke: textStroke }}
      >
      Some text
      </div>
   </main>
)
```

Following the principle of converting kebab case to camel case, I tried `WebkitTextStroke`, which didn't work

When I tried typing "webkit" inside the `style` prop, VS Code suggested "webkitURL", as seen below:

[image: VS Code suggests]

But I could not find a single documentation on it

Is it even possible to use prefixes like `-webkit-` or `-moz-` in JSX (react.js) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was add a comma between between properties like so:

```
style={{
   fontSize: fontSize,
   WebkitTextStroke: textStroke + " black"
}}
```

Big thanks to Konrad Linkowski, I noticed that in a question he linked